# htaccess hide subdirectory name and show only parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wanted to hide the subdirectory name and show only parameter in my localhost so example.com refers to localhost

http://example.com/Main-folder/directory/profile.php?name=Anup

I wanted this url to show as:

http://example.com/Main-folder/Anup

please give me a simple 3-4 line of code (if possible)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^Main-folder/(.*)$ /Main-folder/directory/profile.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Its still not working, i have this code in my .htaccess fileRewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ search.php?tag=$1&page=$2 [L] .... the last line is for the list page i have, and when i am writing same kind of line for profile page (when removing from the profile folder and keeping in the main-folder) the index page of main-folder is not working.